# Is there a way to reset app or activity between espresso tests?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am running espresso tests where a user can click a button to add something to one of our apps activities and I check to make sure that it does indeed add.

I want to run more tests on this activity but with each test I want to have a clean slate for testing.

Is this possible maybe in @After rule?

Edit:
Here is what I have so far but it does not reset. Is there a better way?

```
private lateinit var  activityScenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>

@Before
fun setup() {
    activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)

}

@After
fun tearDown(){
    activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED)
}
```

I also tried:

```
private lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>

@Before
fun setUp() {
    Intents.init()
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    Intents.release()
    scenario.close()
}
```

And example test would be:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
        .putExtra("title", "Testing rules!")
    scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(intent)
//tests
}
```

Update:
I was able to find an answer.

I ended up using AndroidTestOrchestrator.

When using AndroidJUnitRunner version 1.0 or higher, you have access to a tool called Android Test Orchestrator, which allows you to run each of your app's tests within its own invocation of Instrumentation.

Application under test will be cleaned after each test run automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find an answer.

I ended up using [AndroidTestOrchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#kts).

When using AndroidJUnitRunner version 1.0 or higher, you have access to a tool called Android Test Orchestrator, which allows you to run each of your app's tests within its own invocation of Instrumentation.

Application under test will be cleaned after each test run automatically.